# Symfony3 routing in production

Tags: apache, routes, symfony

I have a project using Symfony 3.1 and I'm having quite a hard time during the deployment phase.

My routing is working perfectly in dev environment, using the built in server but in production environment, some routes don't work. They fire a 405 error saying that method is not allowed.

For example, one of the routes that doesn't work is (it fires 405, POST is not allowed, allowed: "GET, HEAD"):

```
http POST http://domain/api/benefits
```

Others work perfectly, such as

```
http GET http://domain/api/benefits
```

I tried to reset the cache via:

```
./bin/console cache:clear -e=prod --no-debug
```

Moreover, if I call to:

```
./bin/console debug:router --env=prod
```

My routes are there. You can see the ouput here:

```
 ----------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------- 
  Name                          Method   Scheme   Host   Path                           
 ----------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------- 
  api_read_benefit              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/{id}             
  api_delete_benefit            DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/{id}             
  api_edit_benefit              PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/{id}             
  api_edit_benefit_picture      POST     ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/picture/{id}     
  api_edit_benefit_attachment   POST     ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/attachment/{id}  
  api_list_benefits             GET      ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/                 
  api_new_benefits              POST     ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/                 
  api_read_entity               GET      ANY      ANY    /api/entities/{id}             
  api_delete_entity             DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/entities/{id}             
  api_list_entities             GET      ANY      ANY    /api/entities/                 
  api_new_entities              POST     ANY      ANY    /api/entities/                 
  logout                        ANY      ANY      ANY    /logout                        
  lang                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /lang                          
  app                           ANY      ANY      ANY    /{url}
```

My routing.yml is:

```
api:
    resource:   "@AppBundle/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api

logout:
    path: /logout

lang:
    path: /lang
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:lang}

app:
    path:     /{url}
    requirements:
            url: ".*"
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Default:index}
```

AppBundle/routing.yml:

```
api_benefits:
    resource:   "@AppBundle/Controller/benefits_routing.yml"
    prefix: /benefits

api_entities:
    resource:   "@AppBundle/Controller/entities_routing.yml"
    prefix: /entities

api_users:
    resource:   "@AppBundle/Controller/entities_routing.yml"
    prefix: /entities
```

AppBundle/Controller/benefits_routing.yml:

```
api_read_benefit:
    path: /{id}
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:read" }
    methods: [GET]
api_delete_benefit:
    path: /{id}
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:delete" }
    methods: [DELETE]
api_edit_benefit:
    path: /{id}
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:edit" }
    methods: [PUT]
api_edit_benefit_picture:
    path: /picture/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:pictureChange" }
    methods: [POST]
api_edit_benefit_attachment:
    path: /attachment/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:attachmentChange" }
    methods: [POST]
api_list_benefits:
    path: /
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:list" }
    methods: [GET]
api_new_benefits:
    path: /
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:Benefits:new" }
    methods: [POST]
```

Any orientation would be highly appreciated since I can't find the problem.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

Just in case, I'm posting my Apache's Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 51.254.96.87:443>
    ServerName domain

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem

    DocumentRoot dir/web
    <Directory dir/web>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                Options -MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>
     <Directory dir/web/bundles>
           <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine Off
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 51.254.96.87:80>
    ServerName domain
    Redirect permanent / https://domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Looks like the route in question is defined for PUT not POST?

Comment: It's not, in the debug it says:
api_new_benefits              POST     ANY      ANY    /api/benefits/
Or am I missing something? It's working perfectly in dev, anyway.

Comment: You are right.  How exactly are you generating the request?  Ajax or an html form.  Html forms are really designed only to POST. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html

Comment: I'm generating it via 3 ways, none works:
1. AngularJS $http -> Ajax
2. Using https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie (curl?)
3. Postman of Chrome

Comment: Not doing any cross domain stuff?

Comment: Not really. As simple as angular trying to post a new "benefit" making that ajax call :/. Weird descovery: GET, DELETE, PUT requests are working all fine. Only POST are failing (actually, only "api_new_benefits" and "api_new_entities" are failing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114748/discussion-between-saso222-and-cerad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it. I opened an issue on the Symfony's Github because it was a problem with the routing php generator:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19064